# Chatterbot with corpus trainer is not running

Tags: chatterbot

If I run chatterbot without corpus trainer it runs properly, but when I try to run the chatterbot with the corpus trainer it doesn't.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

# Create a new instance of a ChatBot
chatbot = ChatBot("FriendlyBot")

# Create a new trainer for the chatbot
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

# Train the chatbot based on the english corpus
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")

# Get a response to the input text 'How are you?'
response = chatbot.get_response("How are you?")

print(response)
```

ChatterBot CorpusTrainer is not working

Comment: define "not working".